# I just had my genome sequenced. Can someone tell me what these different file formats are?

Tags: bioinformatics, human-genome

I just had my whole genome sequenced and now I want to play a bit with bio-informatics. However, the documentation is quite scarce on the file standards used.

These are the files I have been given (the "raw" data):

[image: Image of various file-format icons]

Can someone explain me with some detail what is each file format, and for what are they used?

Transcribed list of file-formats from the picture:

> - Indel (TBI)
> - Indel (VCF)
> - SNP (VCF)
> - SNP (TBI)
> - CNV (TBI)
> - CNV (VCF)
> - BAM (BAI)
> - BAM
> - FASTQ R2
> - FASTQ R1

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because isn't a biology question as defined for this site. Please take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site for details. It might fit within [Bioinformatics.SE], but please check their help pages before posting there. Thanks! 

Comment: "I just sequenced my whole genome": Out of curiosity, how did you do that?

Comment: @tyersome sorry, please forgive me. I actually looked for a bioinformatics stack but google brought me here :X

Comment: @bli I am living with this condition for almost 20 years, and it had no progress, so I though: It probably isn't "cancer/leukemia/MPN" (i.e. a malign for of PV). So it was important to get the raw data to compare my genes with the most recent literature discoveries (standard sequencing tests do not cover most genes that justify this). Now I have the raw data and I already used apps on sequencing.com to browse and search these genes (DanteLabs also has a Gene Browser, but I like to compare). So, what I have found today: (next comment)

Comment: @bli the test used saliva, and there's a debate if saliva is fully germline or not, but either way, given that my JAK2 is neg, and I live with this "PV" for at least 20 years (I have 30) I doubt I have any somatic mutatiion, so it must be congenit... If it were true PV I would maybe be dead by now. So without further ado, I found that: (i) I have a very high chance to develop Hereditary Hemochromatosis (HFE, ELAC2), (ii) then I search for all the genes I could for PV, and I found Familial Erythrocytosis mutations, several SNP mutations in two big genes (EPAS1, EGLN1), and (iii) ...

Comment: @bli ...and (iii) I was suspecting that I also have very high ocygen affinity (gonna test my p50 soon) so I looked for the (apparently ONLY?) documented gene that can cause erythrocytosis with high affinity, these gene is a2-globin gene, and I have a very very clear mutation like this: chr16 173,183 G>A. The paper I learned this from: doi: 10.1111/j.1365-2796.2008.02014.x (Blood p50 evaluation enhances diagnostic definition of
isolated erythrocytosis)

Comment: @bli regards the Hereditary Hemochromatosis, I probably still not have it as my iron levels are normal... But again, I have this form of PV, so they might cancel each other... lol

Comment: @bli probably I am going to organize this data and publish it online freely available to the world (DNA, diagnostics, etc).

Comment: "Polycythemia vera (PV) is a chronic myeloproliferative neoplasm. Virtually all PV patients are iron deficient at presentation and/or during the course of their disease." || So lol, what were the odds? I have no iron deficiency, so maybe my Hematochroma is already here and PV cancels it out, because my iron levels always measured normal in the past (as well as my EPO levels btw - not secondary PV)

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between FASTA, FASTQ, and SAM file formats?](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/q/14/29).

Comment: @PedroD Out of curiosity too, concretely, how do you "sequence your genome" from saliva? Do you do it yourself, using a machine available at your research lab? Or do you send your saliva to a lab (what kind of lab?), what kind of price is it to have your full genome sent as computer files?

Comment: "I just sequenced my whole genome" : this is so cool, sounds like Sci-Fi :)

Comment: No lol, I did it in DanteLabs (they arefrom Italy), and besides the classic reports, they also give you all the raw data in the formats above.

Comment: The machine they used was Illumina nextseq 6000, I paid ~250€, it takes about 2 months

Comment: @PedroD Then perhaps the title should read "I had my genome sequenced..."

Comment: @CarstenS Better now?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

This is a great biological question! It asks a lot about how empirical science is done in the field of modern biology. I'm glad we encourage such questions from curious people who want to learn more.

---

Your genome has a sequence that is unique to you, gifted to you by your parents and by small changes from random chance.

Your genome is pretty close to what is called the [reference genome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_genome), which gets updated — [infrequently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_genome#Human_reference_genome)<sup>1</sup> — as sequencing platforms, pipelines, and algorithms change.

The reference genome is the "standard bearer". All other individual genomes are compared against it. This lets everyone compare apples to apples when trying to say something about the genome, in the aggregate or "big picture" view.

The files associated with the [VCF format](https://samtools.github.io/hts-specs/VCFv4.2.pdf) specify places in your genome that differ from the reference genome — and how they differ. These differences include:

1. [Indels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indel) — insertions or deletions of DNA, as compared with the reference.
2. [SNPs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-nucleotide_polymorphism) — single bases that differ from the reference.
3. [CNVs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-number_variation) — [repeated stretches of DNA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeated_sequence_(DNA)) that differ from repeats in the reference.

The specifics of each of these classes of variants can be associated with various diseases or other attributes that make you unique and interesting. More on that later.

Each of these VCF files in your dataset has an associated TBI file. This is an index file, which helps you to quickly retrieve elements of interest from these datasets using [a command-line tool called `tabix`](http://www.htslib.org/doc/tabix.html).

If you are looking for differences within a specific genomic interval — say, all the differences on chromosome 4, from bases 123456 to 567890 — then you can pass that interval to `tabix` along with your VCF file of interest, and it will return all the indels, SNPs, or CNVs within that range, if there are any within that interval. This subset is VCF-formatted, so by knowing the format, you can get more detail about those differences.

The [BAM-formatted](https://samtools.github.io/hts-specs/SAMv1.pdf) file collects all the individual [sequencing reads in a form that is mapped or aligned to the reference genome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_alignment), along with some summary information to tell you how those reads differ from the reference genome.

As with the VCF files, this BAM file has a BAI index file to go along with it. Like `tabix`, you can use the [`samtools` command-line tool](http://www.htslib.org/doc/samtools.html) to extract the set of reads over your genomic region of interest, if you want to examine them further.

Both `tabix` and `samtools` are available from [the same author](https://github.com/samtools/htslib). If you have questions about these tools, the [Bioinformatics Stack Exchange](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/) site is a great place to ask questions<sup>3</sup>. Lots of bioinformaticists  there have a great deal of experience with those toolkits and can help answer more specific questions.

The two [FASTQ files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTQ_format) are the raw sequence data coming off the sequencer, along with quality data. The sequence reads in these two files are [paired](https://www.illumina.com/science/technology/next-generation-sequencing/plan-experiments/paired-end-vs-single-read.html) for higher quality and longer reads, which makes the sequencing platform faster, cheaper, and better.

I walked a bit backwards, here, on purpose.

The raw FASTQ files are starting material for making the BAM file. The BAM file is then, in turn, used with variant calling software ([example](https://gatk.broadinstitute.org/hc/en-us)) to generate the variation (VCF) datasets.

Why walk backwards through these datasets?

Most people don't care about the raw FASTQ data, except perhaps to do manual alignment or check data quality. What is often more interesting or useful to most is how one's genome differs from the reference, which is captured in the variation data.

Those differences, in aggregate, are how companies like 23andme sell a product<sup>2</sup> that tells you that you are more related to so-and-so population than so-and-so population, or whether you are more or less likely to have some disease or other odd, interesting [phenotypic trait](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phenotype).

<sup>1. Even when new versions of this reference genome are released every few years or so, if you know what original reference genome was used to generate your BAM and VCF files, you can redo analyses based on that knowledge. There is likely some metadata associated with your sequencing results that you can look up to find this out, or you can ask the sequencing center from where you obtained these results.</sup>

<sup>2. For a bit more context, in this answer to another SE question, I talk a bit about SNPs and how they are used for testing association with so-called Mendelian disorders, diseases caused by single base changes, which may be of interest to you given what motivated you to get your genome sequenced, in the first place: https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/88839/5075</sup>

<sup>3. You can ask questions about them here, too, but you'll make certain people grumpy. Better to go to the other SE site for that.</sup>

Comment: OMG this is the most complete explanation I've read. Thank you! You should create a blog post with this, I could not find any that introduced all formats this way, actually the info is scattered around in an unorganized way. Thanks!

Comment: +1, but it seems to be missing an essential piece of information. If the reference genome is regularly updated, how does one know which version of the reference genome the data is relative to?

Comment: @JBentley you can't tell from the file formats (which this question is about). Sometimes the bam files can have indications, but the only way sure way is asking the person who generated the files.

Comment: @JBentley Reference genomes are not updated too frequently. But they do change every few years, and the selection of reference determines the outcome of BAM and VCF files, which are analysis products of the raw FASTQ reads. For humans, a couple common reference genome keywords are `hg38` and, perhaps less so, `hg19`. Perhaps some metadata file not shown here in the question makes use of one of those labels, but as mentioned by @Nicolai, asking the sequencing center where the data come from should get an answer, as well.

Comment: Please have an upvote! I'm a bioinformatician too, and this is an excellent answer. Also, just the fact that someone is able to ask this question suddenly brought into focus how far sequencing has moved on since I started.